# Preserving check box after reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve preserving check box state after reload when check box checked or unchecked and an if statement for check and uncheck. What I am doing wrong or what’s the best way to do it?

```
$('.js-bbCheckbox').click(function(event) {

    $('.js-bbCheckbox').change(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                window.location = '?filter=topRated'; 

            }else{
                window.location = '?filter=nottopRated';
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am not an expert in web programming but I think you need to use cookies to preserve data after a page reload. But I would like to know what others say.

Comment: try looking at [https://github.com/hck/jquery.cookie](https://github.com/hck/jquery.cookie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're able to set the location, but you need the page to change the checkbox based on the filter. This way, you don't need to save a cookie.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var topRated = new RegExp("[?|&]filter=topRated");
        $('.js-bbCheckbox').prop('checked', function () {
            var filter = window.location.search.match(topRated);
            return filter != null;
        }).change(function () {
            window.location = $(this).is(':checked') ? '?filter=topRated' : window.location.toString().replace(topRated, "");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks much, Instead of ?filter=nottopRated can I just get rid of ?filter=topRated in else condition? Basically I dont want any parameter in else condition in my URL.

Comment: @ShoaibUd-Din I edited it to not use the "?filter=nottopRated"

Comment: hmm may be I asked wrong, This is what I would like to do: When I uncheck then ?filter=topRated should get removed from url

Comment: @ShoaibUd-Din this edit should remove the '?filter=topRated' from the url

Comment: Tried it but its not removing.

Comment: Thanks. Be sure to choose the answer you used.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't completely wrong, as it will work.
But once the user closes the page and opens it again, the checkbox will have its default state.

If you want to preserve the checkbox's state between sessions you can use a cookie.
You can set cookies with JavaScript by using the `document.cookie` property, but you'd better look it up because it's kind of complicated.

However, if you're using any server-side technology on this application, you could set the cookie from there. For example, in PHP it would go like this:

```
$_COOKIE['checkbox-topRated'] = isset($_GET['topRated']);
```

And then, when you print the checkbox, you check whether that cookie is true.
That would go like this:

```
$checked = '';
if ($_COOKIE['checkbox-topRated']) {
    $checked = ' checked="checked"';
}

echo '<type input="checkbox" name="topRated"'.$checked.'>';
```